# Angular 2 pasting URL with parameter is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am at my wits end with regards to using router parameters in Angular 2 and was wondering if anyone had faced a similar problem and can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Consider this route setting:

```
{ path: 'content/:id', component: ContentComponent }
```

And then inside the component, I can use the parameter as such:

```
ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
    let id: string = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    ... // do something with this id
}
```

This works when routing is done inside Angular:

```
this.router.navigate(['/content', 'abcde']);
```

But when I paste the same URL into the browser, I get this error:

Url that I paste: `http://localhost/content/abcde`

Erorr:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: 'abcde' ;
>   Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any
>   routes: 'abcde'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me when I was following the documentation on routing.

For some reason I could not understand, it says to set in `index.html`: `<base href=".">`.

Changing the value to `<base href="/">` solved this issue for me.

Comment: If I could upvote this 100 times, I would. Thank you very much. It works and it's not obvious at all. I wasted so much time on this, it's unbelievable! Cheers.

Comment: I know how it feels :) I've wasted time on this as well